# [[maybe_unused]] attribute not working

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, c++17

I am trying to ignore the `unused parameter` warning using the new c++17 attribute `[[maybe_unused]]`, as below.

```
int main([[maybe_unused]] int argc, char** argv)
{
    //...
}
```

But I still get `warning: unused parameter ‘argc’ [-Wunused-parameter]` with the following additional warning.

```
warning: ‘maybe_unused’ attribute directive ignored [-Wattributes]
```

I'm using `g++ (GCC) 7.2.0` with `cmake-3.11.3`. My compiler flags are as follows.

```
-std=c++17 -Wall -pedantic -Wextra -Weffc++
```

I remember using this attribute successfully before, but I have no idea why this is not working now. Could someone show what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: This is C++. If you flat out don't use it just don't name it.

Comment: That warning means that the compiler doesn't support `[[maybe_unused]]`. Works just fine on g++ 7.2 over here however: https://godbolt.org/g/7KnuDx Double check the compiler version, and the compiler flags that are actually used by the generated makefile. That said, as StoryTeller points out,  `[[maybe_unused]]` is redundant in a function argument, since you can simply leave it unnamed instead.

Comment: In current compilers the attribute works as expected: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/csf4Ezvzb

Answer (score 0):

You can suppress warning about unused variable this way:

```
int main(int /* argc */, char** argv)
{
    //...
}
```

or using following trick:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    (void)argc;

    //...
}
```

In this case this code will work for earlier versions of C++ standard and even for pure C.